# How can I get the max value from groupby object with multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Sorry if the question is confusing, I was not sure how to word it. Please let me know if this is duplicated question.

I have a groupby object looks like this:

```
us.groupby(['category_id', 'title']).sum()[['views']]

us

category_id           title                                         views
Autos & Vehicle       1980 toyota corolla liftback commercial       13061
                      1992 Chevy Lumina Euro commercial             18470406
                      2019 Chevrolet Silverado First Look           13061
Music                 Backyard Boys                                 133
                      Eminem - Song                                 1223
                      Cardi B - Wap                                 1111122
Travel & Events       Welcome to Winter PUNderland                  437576
                      What Spring Looks Like Around The World       17554672
```

And I want to get only max value for each category, such as:

```
category_id           title                                         views
Autos & Vehicle       1992 Chevy Lumina Euro commercial             18470406                 
Music                 Cardi B - Wap                                 1111122
Travel & Events       What Spring Looks Like Around The World       17554672
```

How can I do this?

I tried .first() method, and also `us.groupby(['category_id', 'title']).sum()[['views']].sort_values(by='views', ascending=False)[:1]` something like this, but it only gives first row of entire dataframe. Is there any function I can use to only filter max value of groupby object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
us_group = us.groupby(['category_id', 'title']).sum()[['views']]
(us_group.reset_index().sort_values(['views'])
         .drop_duplicates('category_id', keep='last')
)
```